# Related time rate

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

> A particle moves along the circle $$x^2+y^2+4x-8y=108.$$ Determine it's position at the instant when the rate of change of $x$-coordinate is equal to the rate of change of its $y$-coordinate.

Comment: You're not my boss.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that by differentiating $x^2+y^2+4x-8y=108$, we obtain
$$2xx'+2y y'+4x'-8y'=0$$
Now you know that $x'=y'$. Can you take it from here?